# Program entering in a infinite loop only with a specific value

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

I just started with java and while was doing an exercise about permutations (the exercise asked to create a permutation of N elements using an array a[] meeting the requirement that no a[i] is equal to i.) I've created the following code. While testing it, I realized that it entered in a infinite loop sometimes when N = 6 specifically.
Any thoughts on where is the problem?

```
public class GoodPerm {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(arg[0]);

        int[] guests = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            guests[i] = i;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n - i));
            int q = guests[r];
            guests[r] = guests[i];
            guests[i] = q;
            if(guests[i] == i){
                i --;
            }
        }
        for(int q : guests){
            System.out.println(q);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the code enters in a inf-loop in another values, but I didn't found any others.

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity for you to spend some time learning [how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your code.  If you step through your loop, your error should be apparent.

Comment: Yeah the logic here is not _only_ busted at `n = 6`.  I got an infinite loop using `n = 7` as well.  Typically decrementing your loop counter while also incrementing it can lead to errors and one needs to be careful when doing it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it won't be always true again, since ```guests[i] = q``` modifies one part of the equation (sometimes).

Comment: @Islingre Oops, you're right.

Comment: See [Fischer-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for a better algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code can always enter an inf-loop. As I understand the code, you try to do some random switches to achieve your needed result. But if the last element of your array has never been switched, it won't be possible to switch it to any "later/higher" position (because there are no more). In the "last" iteration of your second for-loop (so `i + 1 == n` holds at the beginning) `r` will always evaluate to `i` thus no real switch happens. If the last element is still in place, you gonna repeat this forever.